# Regular expression to make float numbers

Tags: regex, numbers, sublimetext

I have a file with such structure:

```
{8.21689*10^-18}
{2.0033*10^-16}
{1.20201*10^-15}
{4.12718*10^-15}
{1.05284*10^-14}
{2.23678*10^-14}
{4.19995*10^-14}
{7.21721*10^-14}
{1.16019*10^-13}
```

I need to replace

```
*10^-6
```

(for example) with a simple regular expression to a

```
0.000001
```

How can i do that?
And i will also appreciate a lot, if you can advice me a book, or some online lessons, to learn how work with regex.

Comment: What language/tool are you using for this?

Comment: Sublime text editor. There is a replacement tool, that can use regular expressions.

Comment: If you mean that you want to change an expression such as `*10^-n` with `0.0(n-1 times)1` then regular expressions are the wrong tool.

Comment: Mark, I am new in regex. Thought it should help. Why is it wrong? What part can't be done by it?

Comment: As far as your regular expression engine knows, - is just a character. 6 is just a character. Regex doesn't understand what they mean numerically.

Comment: @BuhBuh Thanks, i got it now. I'll make a little script in python to handle this then. Just thought it can be done with replace :P

Comment: Do post it when you get a chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found even easier way, for my purposes(i took that numbers to an array). Thats not what i've asked for, but still worked for me.

I've just replaced `*10^` with `e`

And `3.11154e-18` style numbers were easily parsed by python, coz thats a default float data.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import operator

def prod(lst):
    return reduce(operator.mul, lst, 1)

f = open("new.txt", "r")

buff = ""
array = []

for line in f:
    buff += line
    if "}" in line:
        start = buff.index("{")
        end = buff.index("}")
        array.append([prod(float(factor.strip()) for factor in val.split("*")) for val in buff[start+1:end].split(",")])
        buff = buff[end+1:]

f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved your issue using Excel. It avoids you having to write code. Maybe you can automate with a bit of VB.

Here's the rationale:

- in the first column you can put in your value: `{8.21689*10^-18}`
- in the second column do `=LEN(A1)-FIND("*10^";A1)-4`: determine the position of the power number (e.g. 18). You do minus 4 because of `*10^`
- In the third column, use `=RIGHT(A1;B1)`: that will give you the substring of the value in A1 starting at B1 i.e. it will return `18}` in this example.
- In the 4th column do `=LEFT(C1;LEN(C1)-1)`. That will get you rid of the trailing curly brace and return `18`.
- Finally in the 5th column do `=CONCATENATE("0.";REPT("0";D1-1);"1")`. The reason why you do this is that Excel has the nasty habit of using 1E18 as a notation so that wouldn't solve your issue. The value you then get is: 0.000000000000000001

Here's sample data I tried the Excel sheet with:

{8.21689*10^-18}    3   18} 18  0.000000000000000001
{2.0033*10^-16} 3   16} 16  0.0000000000000001
{1.20201*10^-15}    3   15} 15  0.000000000000001
{4.12718*10^-15}    3   15} 15  0.000000000000001
{1.05284*10^-14}    3   14} 14  0.00000000000001
{2.23678*10^-14}    3   14} 14  0.00000000000001
{4.19995*10^-14}    3   14} 14  0.00000000000001
{7.21721*10^-14}    3   14} 14  0.00000000000001
{1.16019*10^-13}    3   13} 13  0.0000000000001
{1.16019*10^-7} 2   7}  7   0.0000001
{1.16019*10^-117}   4   117}    117 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

All you have to do then is save it as a CSV file.

Comment: I think excel is not the best solution for me, but thanks for your time and result anyways.